# ¿Cómo mostrar un fragment al presionar un botón?

Tags: android, fragment

Amigos, necesito hacer un botón que al presionarlo me abra un fragment, cabe mencionar que el botón está en un fragment.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}




/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                InicioFragment inicioFragment=new InicioFragment();
                return inicioFragment;
            case 1:
                VideosFragment videosFragment=new VideosFragment();
                return videosFragment;
            case 2:
                GaleriaFragment galeriaFragment=new GaleriaFragment();
                return galeriaFragment;
            case 3:
                UbicacionFragment ubicacionFragment=new UbicacionFragment();
                return ubicacionFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Inicio";
            case 1:
                return "Videos";
            case 2:
                return "Fotos";
            case 3:
                return "Maps";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**InicioFragment.java**

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {

public InicioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);



    return rootView;
}

}
```

**fragment_inicio.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Yucatán" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Riviera Maya" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Tulum" />
```

Tengo Un tab para mostrar pestañas. lo que quiero es que al presionr el botón de Yucatán me mande o me muestre información de otro fragment, o sea que sustituya el fragment de inicio y me muestre uno nuevo. El fragment que quiero que se muestre tiene este código:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**YucatanContentFragment.java**

```
public class YucatanContentFragment extends Fragment {


public YucatanContentFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yucatan_content, container, false);
}

}
```

**fragment_yucatan_content.xml**

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Aquí irá la información!" />
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar que tiene hecho hasta hora y que es lo que has intentado para que la gente pueda ayudarte

Comment: Como menciona @Joacer, edita tu pregunta y agrega todo el código de tu _fragment_ para partir desde ahí no desde 0, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear un Button:

```
private Button verYucatan;
```

Luego cargar el btn desde la vista:

```
verYucatan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button10);
```

Debes usar el evento setOnClickListener de esta manera:

```
verYucatan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Aqui llamas el fragment que necesitas
        //Creas el nuevo fragmento y una nueva transacción.
        Fragment nuevoFragmento = new YucatanContentFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Siguiendo tu código seria algo así:

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {

private Button verYucatan;

public InicioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        verYucatan = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button10);


        verYucatan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Aqui llamas el fragment que necesitas
                //Creas el nuevo fragmento y una nueva transacción.
                 Fragment nuevoFragmento = new YucatanContentFragment();
                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
                 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                 transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Todo esto en qué clase debería estar?, de antemano muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Tiene que ir en el controlador que contiene el botón Yucatán, es decir en **InicioFragment.java** edite la respuesta para que te sea mas claro entenderlo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, en seguida lo implemento. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Con gusto, si ha sido útil recuerda marca la respuesta como correcta con el check verde.

Comment: si amigo, solo una pregunta, en esta linea me muestra un error  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento); especificamente en fragment_container

Comment: Que te aparece en la excepción?

Comment: al compilar me sale esto: Error:(46, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable fragment_container

Comment: Muy bien, la forma es muy paso a paso, aunque me parece que hay una forma de simplificar en menos líneas. Saludos!!